# After I use the forin collectionView.visibleCells to set the cell.selected to NO, selected other they are auto selected again

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

My collection view is like upper, when the selected cell all disappear I was invoke an action:

```
- (IBAction)clearAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    for (CustomCell *cell in self.buy_code_cv.visibleCells) {

        if (cell.selected) {
            [cell setSelected: NO];
        }

    }
}
```

In the Custom Cell's `.m` file: I override the `setSelected:` method:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {

    [super setSelected:selected];

    //self.selected = !selected;


    if (selected) {
        self.backView.backgroundColor = APP_COLOR;
        self.number_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.multiple_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
    // uncheck
    else {

        self.backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.number_label.textColor = HexRGB(0x999999);
        self.multiple_label.textColor = HexRGB(0xcccccc);
    }

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedCustomCell:)]) {

        [self.delegate didSelectedCustomCell:self];
    }

}
```

How to solve this issue in UICollectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UICollectionViewCell` is a merely a representation of the collection view state, it does not hold the state of the collection view.  An item that is offscreen may be selected, in which case there won't even be a `UICollectionViewCell` instance for that item.

Rather than updating the cell directly, you need to tell the collection view to deselect the item and have it take care of updating any on-screen cells.

```
- (IBAction)clearAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.buy_code_cv.indexPathForSelectedItems) {

        [self.buy_code_cv deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that maintain array of index when you select any cell.
In this method

```
 -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
 didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      if ([self.arraySelected containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]])
     {
           [self.arraySelected removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
     }
    else
    {
      [self.arraySelected addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }

  [collectionView reloadData];
}
```

And Write this code is in this method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.arraySelected containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]) {
    self.backView.backgroundColor = APP_COLOR;
    self.number_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.multiple_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}
// uncheck
else {

    self.backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.number_label.textColor = HexRGB(0x999999);
    self.multiple_label.textColor = HexRGB(0xcccccc);
}
 return cell;
}
```